# execution of .jar file from python doesn't work

Tags: python, executable-jar, yui-compressor

I am trying to minify multiple js files by yuicompressor.jar called from python.
Here is the code:

```
import os, subprocess
root = r"c:\myfloder"
minifier = '"c:\yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"'
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
         fullFile = os.path.join(path, name)
         if name.endswith(".js"):
            minifyCommand = ' --disable-optimizations '+'"'+fullFile+'"' +" -o "+'"'+fullFile+"min"+'"'
            subprocess.call(["java","-jar",minifier,minifyCommand])
print "done"
```

The only problem is that it does't do the job, I mean the output files are not created. I have printed that and put it into command line and everything worked. Any idea?

Comment: Well, first of all, I would try and see what is going on by printing:
  " ".join(["java","-jar",minifier,minifyCommand]). That is the commnad going into the subprocess call. Does this command work outside Python in the very folder given by the variable "path"?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I have already printed it and it worked in command line perfectly. I have just printed it with manual combination and space separating (like ..."-jar" + " "+ minifier...). With your suggestion with .join the command was without spaces like "java-jar"c:\myfloder\myfile.js...". So I try to add spaces into the call (like " -jav "). but it doesn't work.

Comment: careful, there is a space in between the "":  "          ".join(["java", "-jar"...])

Comment: minifier = '"c:\yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"'   Could putting double quotes AND single quotes be an issue here? I don't know why you need to do that, in any case. Same goes for the thing around fillFile in minifyCommand,... Are you absolutely certain it works when you run, from the folder where your original code is, the exact command as seeing just before the call to the subprocess.call?

Comment: the mixing of double quotes with single quotes is only because I have spaces in paths like (c:\my documents\...) and in the command line this is the issue, it however works when the path is quoted. But just to be sure, I have put those files into paths with no spaces, removed that quoting from script, but still no success. And yes I am completely sure that the command printed from " ". join... works from code folder, and every other folder I have tried. I am quite desperate and I am on the verge of struggle this into dos based batch file...

Comment: so I have give it one last try with: <code> fullCommand = " ".join(["java","-jar",minifier,minifyCommand]) os.system(fullCommand)</code> and it worked like charm. But my question is still why subprocess.call() didn't work. I have python 2.7, could this be the issue?

Comment: I'm at a lost here... My only bullet left is: try subprocess.call(fullCommand, shell=True), but I wouldn't be able to tell you why, even if it worked :(

Comment: Well, it worked. But shadow of mystery remains. Anyway, thank you very much for your willingness and time.